# AVPlayer - UILabel not visible when video starts playing in ios

Tags: ios, uilabel, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a UILabel over my video player.

On load of the video controller the label is showing, as soon as the video starts its hiding.

I have already tried these below steps to overcome this issue but no luck:-

1) self.captionLbl.layer.zPosition = 1;
2) [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.captionLbl];

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which view your label is added.

Suppose your view is videoLayerView and it is added as subView to your View.

then,
videoLayerView.layer.zPosition = 1;

Comment: then try,
 [self.view sendSubviewToBack:videoLayerView];